# Pretty Tables in C

Tags: c, pretty-print

Are there any libraries/function available in C to pretty print tabular data. I am looking for something like this : http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/

Comment: Not that I know of, but should be quite easy to make, especially if you can look at the Python solution (which looks pretty straight-forward).

Comment: If you want to render a table in ASCII (or maybe even using UTF8) you could take a look at the [NCurses library](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Comment: Ncurses is nice :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement something as generic-looking as the Python module seems to be, one problem is going to be data storage. It's not so easy to just throw stuff into a list in C, of course. You might want to look at [glib's](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) `GVariant` solution for instance. It would be pretty easy to build a table-formatter handling any reasonable type of value based on that.